# LDAP authentication, roles assigned to ldap hierarchical groups not working ? Version v2.23.2

Tags: geoserver

I am a new GeoServer user and I am attempting to establish security rules based on hierarchical LDAP groups. It works fine on child groups but not on parent groups.

I have created a new role and defined a rule for reading a workspace. The LDAP group/user service is functioning correctly, as I can view users and groups without any issues. The hierarchical groups are configured and working well. When I view a parent group, I can see users, both direct members and members of child groups. Everything works perfectly in this regard.

The LDAP authentication provider is properly configured, and authorization utilizes the user/group LDAP service.

Now, when I add the role to a child group (where my user is a direct member), everything works as expected, and the user can see the workspace layers.

However, when I add the role to a parent group, it does not work. The user is unable to access the workspace layer. Is this a limitation of GeoServer?